# How to take Float value from JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextfield

```
JTextField text=new JTextField();
text.gettext();
```

//I want text.gettext(); value to be a float value to calculate a problem . How to take it as ??

Comment: check out the [`Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) class, you might find something there

Comment: He would rather check the Float class as he askes for that not for Double. Also this might be duplicate of String to float parsing

Comment: If your question is _not_ a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach and describe nay problems you encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to read a float from a text field you can do it two ways.

```
String a=text.getText();//Create a string to store the incoming data
float f = Float.parseFloat(a);// to cast the data
```

Else

```
float f = Float.parseFloat(text.getText);
```